# How to convert a date in this format "Mar 31 2018" from string to date in Athena / Presto?

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

Using amazon Athena I am created a table from CSV file, following is the query created by athena, however issue is that I am not able to get dated field in date format even if I replace string as date.  In csv file date is in format  Apr 01 2018;

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.invoice (
  `cust_id` string,
  `invoice_id` string,
  `dated` string,
  `from` string,
  `to` string,
  `amount` decimal,
  `sgst` decimal,
  `total_amount` decimal,
  `amt_words` string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://snt-csv/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`date_parse`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) with `'%b %d %Y'` format and cast the result to `date`.

```
presto> select cast(date_parse('Apr 01 2018', '%b %d %Y') as date);
   _col0
------------
 2018-04-01
```